# Layout is not properly displayed in different smartphones

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I am not able to show the XML file in smartphone as it is shown in android studio. In some smartphones bottom space is blank below the ads and in some smartphones it is properly displayed.

Please correct my XML code it is given below. Thanks in advance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Version">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="470dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tV"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"

            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:text="@string/version"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            app:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-light">
        </TextView>
    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/white">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/zoomout"
            android:layout_width="38dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:background="@drawable/zoom_out"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/trans_punjabi"
            android:layout_width="38dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/zoonin"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:background="@drawable/translation"
            ></Button>


        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar"
            android:layout_width="277dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="45dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/zoomout"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/zoonin"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/zoomout"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/zoonin" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/zoonin"
            android:layout_width="38dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:background="@drawable/zoom_in"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
        </Button>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center"
            android:background="@color/white">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
            android:background="@drawable/forward" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-3dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="-3dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button"
            android:background="@drawable/pauses" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
            android:background="@drawable/plays" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
            android:background="@drawable/rewind" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:foregroundGravity="clip_horizontal"
            android:gravity="clip_horizontal|center"
            android:paddingLeft="14dp"
            android:text="0:0"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button4"
            android:foregroundGravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingRight="14dp"
            android:text="5:23"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want the textview(it is a long text with scroll) to be displayed at top, ads to be displayed at the bottom and there should be no blank space at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is that you have linear, vertical layout, which contains one fixed size widget (`ScrollView`) and few `wrap_content`s - sum of these values (after measuring) is also fixed size/height, so on some devices (especially large) it will be smaller than available space. try to avoid fixed size declarations like this: `android:layout_height="470dp"`, especially for `ViewGroup`s/parents of `View`s

use `RelativeLayout` as a root layout and inside use `layout_above`, `layout_alignParentBottom` and `layout_alignParentAbove` attrs

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        .../>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttons_lower_row"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/adView"
        .../>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttons_upper_row"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/buttons_lower_row"
        .../>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/buttons_upper_row"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        .../>
</RelativeLayout>
```

`View` placed at bottom (`AdView`) is declared at first. then next `View` (one above ad) is declared with `android:layout_above="@id/adView"`, and so on. last `ScrollView` have both `layout_above` and `layout_alignParentTop` - will fit to empty space left

PS. `layout_above=<id>` you can imagine like `this_layout_should_be_above_layout_with_id=<id>`, there is also `layout_below`, `layout_toRightOf` and `layout_toLeftOf`. all these are aligning `View`s edge-to-edge in `RelativeLayout`

Answer (score 0):

I you want to set fixed size for your widgets you can use this [library](https://github.com/intuit/sdp). It will scale the widgets accoeding to screen size.